# IsSoftDeleted always return null - Azure AD provisioning

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, provisioning

As per Microsoft document, `IsSoftDeleted` returns true when one or more of the following conditions are met:

1. User is disabled in Azure AD (accountEnabled = False)
2. User is soft-deleted in Azure AD
3. User was previously assigned to application and is unassigned, AND provisioning is set to "Sync assigned users and groups"
4. User was previously in scope based on scoping filters set on the User attribute mapping section and now is not in scope

I get a null value for `IsSoftDeleted` when mapping to a value for provisioning. I have tried each of the following in the Expression builder with their respective results:

```
[IsSoftDeleted] => null

Not([IsSoftDeleted]) => null

Switch([IsSoftDeleted], , "False", "True", "True", "False") => null (not matching "False" or "True" so defaulting to null)

Switch([IsSoftDeleted], "False", "False", "True", "True", "False") => False (not matching "False" or "True" so defaulting to "False")

Switch([IsSoftDeleted], "True", "False", "True", "True", "False") => True (not matching "False" or "True" so defaulting to "True")
```

I also tried the previous three with actual booleans (so false, false, true, true, false etc) all with corresponding, incorrect, responses.

It appears that `IsSoftDeleted` is just not responding as required in my setup. Any thoughts on how I can enable it correctly?

I checked with expression builder but I always get `null`.